# Permission error when logging into Heroku from command line

Tags: bash, authentication, heroku, permissions, command-line-interface

When I try to login with

`$heroku login`

I am sent to the browser to log in, but upon return I receive this error:

```
heroku: Waiting for login...
Logging in... done
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:/Users/<My User>/_netrc'
```

I tried opening that file and I saw the password was incorrect so I changed it on heroku and in the file. Still have the error. I wonder if it is saying that it doesn't have permission to open that file?

Answer (score 0):

Find the `_netrc` file. Open settings and toggle readonly to on, save, then turn off.

Comment: what if it doesnt exist ?

Comment: not sure...did you check for hidden files?

Comment: I have it resolved, it was hidden.  Thanks!